# How to change color of empty rows in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to change color of empty rows in a DataGridView

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgv1.Rows)  
if (r.Value.ToString() == "")
//if (r.Cells.Value.ToString() == "") - also trying
r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
```

but Row has no definiton for Value, and Cells need to be specified by Column.
How can I do this, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you'll need to check all the `Cells`. Here's how you can do that using LINQ:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dgv1.Rows) {
    if(r.Cells.All(c => c.Value.ToString() == string.Empty)) {
        r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
    }
}
```

Comment: ThankYou, minitech. Solved, but it should be a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgv1.Rows)  
if (r.Cells["YourImportantFieldNameLikeID"].Value == null)
r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
```

if you do not want to see the last empty row you can disable it with:

```
DataGridViewName.AllowUserToAddRows = False;
```